# Prove $\prod\limits_{d|n}d =n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove $\prod\limits_{d|n}d =n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}$
First, I am confused by the notation in this problem and understanding what it is I am actually trying to prove. Also, I do not know where to begin proving this problem

Comment: $d\mid n$ means $d$ is a divisor of $n$, so $\prod\limits_{d\mid n}d$ is the product of all divisors of $n$. For $n = 6$ for example, $1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 6 = 36$. $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Comment: Hint: Each divisor as an equal and opposite divisor :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(n) = \prod_{d \vert n} d \tag{$\star$}$ Note that if $d \vert n$, then so does $\dfrac{n}d$. Hence, we also have that $S(n) = \prod_{d \vert n} \dfrac{n}d \tag{$\dagger$}$ Multiplying $\star$ and $\dagger$, we get that
$$S(n)^2 = \prod_{d \vert n}d \prod_{d \vert n} \dfrac{n}d = \prod_{d \vert n}\left(d \cdot \dfrac{n}d \right) = \prod_{d \vert n} n = n^{d(n)}$$
From this, we get that
$$S(n) = n^{d(n)/2}$$

Answer (score -1):

The $\Pi$ notation means product. With the subscript $d \mid n$, it's saying "multiply all divisors of n". The $d(n)$ function in the exponent refers to the *divisor function*. You can probably take it from there.

Hope this helps!